# Query having rows and columns based on a single column with aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have sample data, please can someone help me create the output based on the following data?

```
CREATE TABLE Data 
(
     StudentId int 
    ,subject varchar(50)
    , Flag varchar(2)
)

INSERT INTO Data 
VALUES (1, 'Art', 'Y'),
(1, 'Chemistry','Y'),
(2,'Art','Y'),
(3, 'Art','Y'),
(3, 'Chemistry','y')
```

Output:

```
            | Art Chemistry
------------|--------------
Art         |  3         2
Chemistry   |  2         2
```

Comment: What is the 1st column? Can you explain your expected results?

Comment: We far prefer formatted text for you output over images - so I have rolled back your changed. Please leave as text.

Comment: It did not let me enter my table , soory, i attached the o utput as a pic.

Comment: Can i know how to format as a table please ? @DaleK

Comment: @spboutput how you have done it is perfectly fine. But a quick google shows https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . This looks like a self join and aggregation:

```
select d1.StudentId,
       sum(case when d2.subject = 'Art' then 1 else 0 end) as art,
       sum(case when d2.subject = 'Chemistry' then 1 else 0 end) as chemistry
from data d1 join
     data d2
     on d1.StudentId = d2.StudentId
group by d1.StudentId;
```

Comment: thank you, is there a way i can do this dynamically for every year students ( like Y1, Y2 ??)

Answer (score 1):

Group by subject, only sum if the value is Art or Chemistry

```
select 
    d1.subject,
    sum( iif( d2.subject ='Art', 1, 0 )) as Art,
    sum( iif( d2.subject ='Chemistry', 1, 0 )) as Chemistry
from Data d1 
join Data d2   
    on d1.StudentId = d2.StudentId
group by d1.subject;
```

Comment: So identical to the existing answer, just using `iif` instead of `case`? Hmmm not really an improvement.

Comment: the other answer groups by StudentID and doesn't produce the correct response.

Comment: Then you would normally comment on their answer and give them a chance to correct it.